# loop through files in a directory using javascript in html script tag

Tags: javascript, foreach, bundles

Is there a way to loop through some files in script tag in html head section?

I am looking for something like this:

```
<head>
  <script>
   let path = './areas/js/build/bundles/";
   foreach(file in path) {
    // do something
   }
  </script>
</head>
```

There are some dynamically created bundles that I need to loop through them in my script tag of my html file.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Javascript does not have access to any file system when executed in a browser.

Answer (score 3):

You can't in Javascript. For security reasons, you cannot access a user's file system - even if it's your own.

What you want to achieve is done with back-end technologies such as PHP, ASP.net, etc, etc.

In PHP, you would do something like:

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('./areas/js/build/bundles/') as $fileInfo) {
    echo $fileInfo->getFilename();
}
```